# OS X can't update PHP by homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I want to install PHP7.2
I ran the command below:

```
$ brew install php@7.2
Error: You are using macOS 10.10.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

My PC can't update anymore.
What should I do?

Comment: Try installing PHP by yourself; Homebrew doesn’t support macOS 10.10.